# Define const level class in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want define a class `Const` to reuse and easier to handle edit, manternance. Example:

[My issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6luy.png)

But Dart Analysis has 2 warnings such as:

```
error: The const variable 'String' must be initialized.
error: Expected to find ';'.
```

Answer (score 0):

There's isn't any line #5 in your class, neither any `String` variable. Try refreshing your IDE

Perhaps the log you are getting is from some previous build!

Comment: Thanks bro very much. Every thing is okay.